# $\forall v (d_v \ge (\delta \ge 4))\Rightarrow $ $G$ has two cycles of length at least $\delta+1$

Tags: graph-theory

If every degree's vertex of graph $G(V,E)$ bigger than $\delta\ge 4$. Prove $G$ has two cycles of length at-least  $\delta+1$ with disjoint edges.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It looks to me like induction is the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I try eliminate one of the cycle and wanna proof exist another. but I don't use Induction.let me think about it and thx about your hint.

Comment: Any restrictions on $\delta$? The question doesn't work with $\delta = 2$. Consider $K_4$ and note that it doesn't have two cycles of length 3.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say two cycles of length 3 with disjoint edges.

Comment: Is a degree of each vertex *bigger than* ($>$) $\delta$ or *at least* ($\ge$) $\delta$? Should the lengths of the cycles be *exactly* $\delta+1$ or *at least* $\delta+1$? (in the first case a complete bipartite graph $K_{\delta+1, \delta+1}$ should be a counterexample for even $\delta$). Can on of the cycles contain a vertex more than once (for instance, as in the case $v_1-v_2-v_3-v_1-v_4-v_5-v_1$?)

Comment: @AlexRavsky you are right I think I forget type at-least word ,Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas to reach the above result, I hope that someone can develop them.

**$1^{st}$ Idea:**

By probabilistic method:

number of edges in $G$ graph is at least $$\frac{\delta v(G)}{2}\geq 2v(G)$$

So by choosing at least $\frac{1}{2}\delta v(G)$ edges from $\frac{1}{2}v(G)(v(G)-1)$ we must be sure that we have two cycles that are edge disjoint of lenght at least $\delta +1$ each.

**$2^{nd}$ Idea:**

By taking the subgraph $T'_{\delta,\delta}$ ( which is a  sort of tree subgraph as described below).

A $d$-regular tree is a tree in which all vertices have a degree of $d$ or 1 ( degree of leaves is 1, and degree of the  rest vertices is $d$).

Let $T_{d,l}$ be $d$-regular tree with $l$ levels.

**Example:** the following graph is $T_{3,4}$

[image]

Let $T'_{d,l}$ be the graph defined from $T_{d,l}$ in the following way:  connect  each leave( *i.e.* vertex of degree one) to  exactly one other leave from every branch.

**Notes:** 1-branch is the set of vertices that all have the same neigbor of the root as there ancestor.
2-ancestors of a vertex are the set of vertices that form the path from the root of the tree to this vertex.

**Example:** The following graph is $T'_{3,3}$

[image]

Now by taking the subgraph $T'_{\delta,\delta}$  we must reach the result.

Comment: If you could explain the first idea more in depth for me, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Amir We may use this theorem which is stated in Bondy and Murty book page 335::: In the sequel, we are concerned with probability spaces $(\Omega_n, P_n)$ which are defined
for all positive integers $n$. Because it is with sparse graphs that we are mostly concerned, we study the behaviour of the probability space $G_{n,p}$ when $p$ is a function of $n$ and $p(n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow  \infty$. Given a sequence $(\Omega_n,P_n)$ , of probability
spaces, a property A is said to be satisfied almost surely if  $P_n(A_n) \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow  \infty$ where $An = A\cap \Omega_n$